# Problema con notificaciones entrantes

Tags: firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, push-notification

Estoy usando Postman y Firebase para enviar un mensaje de notificación a varios usuarios, esas notificaciones se muestran en una actividad usando recyclerView y cardView. El problema que tengo es que esas notificaciones no pueden aparecer automáticamente. Tengo que ir a la actividad anterior y luego ingresar a la actividad de notificaciones para que estas se muestren

Este es el código que tengo

```
class ventanaNotif : AppCompatActivity() {


val notifList = ArrayList<Notificaciones>()
lateinit var adapter: NotifAdapter
lateinit var shared: SharedPreferences
private val PREF = "Notificaciones"
private val COUNT_KEY = "Conteo"
var borrar: ImageButton? = null

var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null

lateinit var onMessageReceived: RemoteMessage
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventana_notif)

    setRecyclerView()

    borrar = findViewById(R.id.butBorrar)
    //
    shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY, 0)


    notifData()

                      


}



fun setRecyclerView() {

    adapter = NotifAdapter(notifList)

    rv_notif.adapter = adapter
    rv_notif.setHasFixedSize(true)
}



   



fun notifData() {

    shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY, 0)

    for ((x, valor) in (1..count).withIndex()) {


        notifList.add(
            Notificaciones(
                "${shared.getString("TituloData${valor}", "Todo bien")}",
                "${shared.getString("CuerpoData${valor}", "No hay más notificaciones")}",
                "${shared.getString("FechaData${valor}", "Sin fecha ")}"
            )
        )

        adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.itemCount)

    }}


}
```

Estoy tratando de usar notifyItemInserted para mostrar la última notificación automáticamente, pero no funciona. Tengo que ir a la actividad anterior y luego a la actividad de notificaciones para mostrar todas las notificaciones.

Esta es la clase que ocupo cuando una notificación llega.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {


private lateinit var shared: SharedPreferences
private lateinit var editor:SharedPreferences.Editor
lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
lateinit var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel
lateinit var builder : Notification.Builder
private val channelId =  "com.steren.sterenconsultoria"
private val description = "Test notification"


private val COUNT_KEY = "Conteo"


override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    if (remoteMessage.data != null){

        Log.e("Error", "Este es mi mensaje ${remoteMessage.notification?.title}")

        shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY,0)
        count++
        editor = shared.edit()
        editor.putString("TituloData${count}", remoteMessage.data?.get("title").toString())
        editor.putString("CuerpoData${count}", remoteMessage.data?.get("body").toString())
        editor.putString("FechaData${count}", remoteMessage.data?.get("fecha").toString())
        editor.putString("UrlData${count}", remoteMessage.data?.get("url").toString())
        editor.apply()
        //guardando las variables de shared preferences
        editor.putInt(COUNT_KEY, count).apply()

        Log.e("Notificaciones", "Este es mi contador ${count}")


        //Handler identifica si llega una notificación y la pasa
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {

            notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            //Intent para que desde la notificación te mande a la ventanaNotif
            val intent = Intent (this, ventanaNotif::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            //Recupera el cuerpo del Layout armado para la notificación
            val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName,R.layout.notification_layout)
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title, remoteMessage.data.get("title"))
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_body, remoteMessage.data.get("body"))


            //Construcción de la notificación
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel =
                    NotificationChannel(channelId,description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH) //Importancia alta para la notifiación
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true) //LED de notificaciones si lo tiene
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE //Color azúl si se presta
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(false) //Permite vibración por default apagado
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) //crea la notificación


                //versiones nuevas de android (> Android 8)
                builder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_steren)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_steren))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

            } else { //Si es menor de android 8 entonces quitamos el chanelID
                builder = Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_steren)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
            }
            notificationManager.notify(1234,builder.build()) //Manda la notifación

            

           //Toast

            toast_info2(remoteMessage.data.get("title").toString(),
                remoteMessage.data.get("body").toString())
           

            //badge


        }


    }



}
```

}

Me parece que tengo que pasar un valor para cuando llegue una notificación se agregue en tiempo real a la ventana donde se muestran todas mis notificaciones

Esperaba si ustedes pudieran ver el error que estoy comentiendo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola rodri , la notificacion se muestra tanto en la barra de estado como adentro de la app o solo necesitas que la notificacion se muestre dentro de la app ? Es decir que aparezca mientras el usuario esta usando la app ?

Comment: Hola, Gastón. Necesito que aparezcan mientras el usuario está en el activity donde se muestra el cuerpo de todas las notificaciones. Me parece que es porque no sabe cuando están llegando en el momento. En la parte de arriba pondré mi clase para las Notificaciones de Firebase

Answer (score 0):

en onMessageReceived() agrega esto:

```
 if (remoteMessage.data.isEmpty()) {
         
//Aquí creas NotificationBuilder 

 val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoblanco)
            .setColor(rgb(255, 255, 255))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 100, 500, 1000))
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

/*En mi caso es este*/
```

Para que la notificación llegue cuando esta usando la aplicación

Comment: Muchas gracias. Liss. Ya tenía un Notification Builder agregado. Mi problema es que las notificaciones las agrupo dentro de una Activity y no llega en tiempo real :(